# Running more than one Grails application on Amazon's EC2

Tags: grails, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can I run more than one Grails application on a virtual Linux machine in Amazon's cloud? I start one application on port 8080 and the other on say port 8090? Basically, I am trying to run two versions of the same application, one that testers can use to test and the other on which I can continue development. I seem to be able to launch the second application but I cannot get to it with my browser. The way I am doing it now is launching the first application by grails run-war and the development version with grails run-app of course. I can get to my first application by doing www.hostname.com:8080 but the one on www.hostname.com:8090 is not available in the browser.

Comment: You can check if the other grails application is actually running on port 8090. Type the following command on the commandline: `telnet localhost 8090`. If you see a `Connected to localhost.` message it means that it is running, but the port might just be blocked on the machine's firewall.

Comment: Also make sure that port 8090 is open in the EC2 Security Group.

Comment: You should really start learning something about apache :)

Comment: Port 8090 was indeed blocked in the security group rules. Thanks guys.

Comment: @injecteer You are correct my friend. The time for me to do that has come and that is what I am struggling with now.